# Should I worry about cross-contact or cross-contamination inside food production factories?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, food

I live in Portugal. Here are some supermarket chains such as "Continente", "Pingo Doce" etc. They sell their own brand foods and also other brands' foods. For instance: Continente sells vegetable salads, vegetable sandwich, vegetable soups etc. They do NOT have "suitable for vegetarians" label. Their ingredient lists don't seem to have any animal-derived or Haram ingredients. But I have a concern. Do I need to know, whether there is any **cross-contact** (or cross-contamination) between vegetarian and non-vegetarian foods in the Continente food factories? What usually happens in these kind of factories?
Please help....

Comment: Why would you need to know? I don’t see anything haram here except the meat if it’s halal or not (slaughtered or not).

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. Its very important to make sure your food is not contaminated. I would ask the company itself as to how they package their foods. But in my opinion if they are packaging vegetable foods or using a conveyor belt then they would not have meats mixed with that. But you can always call them to find out.

**Have a nice day!**

Comment: Hi ... Thanks for your reply. May I know where do you live? What about Walmart in USA? Do you think contamination happens there? And, if the ingredients' list doesn't contain any animal derived or haram thing, does it mean that there is no cross contamination in the production line?

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, i hope you are doing fine. Yes, i live in the United States. I like Walmart lol. So I believe that many products will state that this product is used with other things like nuts, milk or something like that. I think you might have seen that on the back label of some products. I would call the company if you are in doubt.